# React native, <TouchableWithoutFeedback /> doesn't work when I open screen for the second time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>` to dismiss keyboard on press. But I have a problem: when I open screen for the first time it works as expected, but on second screen opening it stop working. I don't undrestand why this happens. And also I can't find any workaround not to use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` if you know any please tell me.
Here is my code:

```
const Map = ({navigation, route}: HomeNavigationProps<"Map">) => {
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
    const [satellite, setSatellite] = useState(false);
    const [showModalWindow, setShowModalWindow] = useState(false);
    const [currentMarker, setCurrentMarker] = useState(initialMarker);
    const [navigationDestination, setCurrentNavigationDestination] = useState(null);
    const [currentUserLocation, setCurrentUserLocation] = useState(undefined);
    const [destination, setDestination] = useState(undefined);
    const [regionParams, setRegionParams] = useState(undefined);
    const [showText, setShowText] = useState(true);
    const [markerPressed, setMarkerPressed] = useState(false);

    const mapView = React.createRef();
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();
    const onMarkerPress = (marker) => {
        setMarkerPressed(true);
        navigation.navigate('ModalWindow', {
            markerId: marker.id,
            screen: 'Map',
            mapType: satellite ? 'satellite' : 'default'
        });
    }

    const sendDataToParent = (index) => { 
        setShowModalWindow(index);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            let {status} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
                const initialLocation = {
                    coords: {
                        latitude: 55.751244,
                        longitude: 37.618423
                    }
                }
                setCurrentUserLocation(initialLocation)
            } else {
                try {
                    const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({accuracy: 6})
                    setCurrentUserLocation(location);
                } catch (e) {
                    const initialLocation = {
                        coords: {
                            latitude: 55.751244,
                            longitude: 37.618423
                        }
                    }
                    setCurrentUserLocation(initialLocation)
                }
            }
        })();
        if (route.params && currentUserLocation || destination && currentUserLocation) {
            if (destination && route.params && !markerPressed) {
                mapView.current.setCamera({
                    center: {
                        latitude: parseFloat(route.params.destination.latitude),
                        longitude: parseFloat(route.params.destination.longitude)
                    },
                    pitch: 0.1,
                    heading: 0.1,
                    zoom: 100,
                    altitude: 10
                }, {duration: 1000});
                route.params = false;
            }
            if (markerPressed && destination) {
                mapView.current.setCamera({
                    center: {
                        latitude: parseFloat(destination.latitude),
                        longitude: parseFloat(destination.longitude)
                    },
                    pitch: 0.1,
                    heading: 0.1,
                    zoom: destination.zoom,
                    altitude: 10
                }, {duration: 1000});
                route.params = false;
                setMarkerPressed(false);
            }
        }

        if (errorMsg) {
            console.log(errorMsg);
        }
        fetch('https://', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({data: ['all']}),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        // const interval = setInterval(() => {
        //     setShowText((showText) => !showText);
        // }, 700);
        // return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [isFocused]);
const navigateToUserPosition = () => {
        mapView.current.animateCamera({
            center: {
                latitude: parseFloat(currentUserLocation.coords.latitude),
                longitude: parseFloat(currentUserLocation.coords.longitude)
            },
            pitch: 0.1,
            heading: 0.1,
            zoom: 15,
            altitude: 50
        }, {duration: 1000});
    }
        if (currentUserLocation && data) {
            return (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}
                                          accessible={false}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    {satellite ? <StatusBar style="light"/> : <StatusBar style="black"/>}
                    <MapView
                        customMapStyle={customMapStyle}
                        ref={mapView}
                        // clusterColor='#FFE8E9'
                        mapType={satellite ? "hybrid" : "standard"}
                        style={{flex: 1}}
                        showsUserLocation={true}
                        followsUserLocation={true}
                        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                        onRegionChangeComplete={region => {setDestination(region)}}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: parseFloat(currentUserLocation.coords.latitude),
                            longitude: parseFloat(currentUserLocation.coords.longitude),
                            latitudeDelta: 3,
                            longitudeDelta: 3,
                        }}
                    >
                        {data.map(marker => {
                            const latitude = parseFloat(marker.coordinates.latitude)
                            const longitude = parseFloat(marker.coordinates.longitude)
                            return (
                                <Marker
                                    tracksViewChanges={false}
                                    onPress={
                                        () => onMarkerPress(marker)
                                    }
                                    coordinate={
                                        {latitude, longitude}
                                    }
                                >

                                    {
                                        marker.type == "mountains" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlMountain}/> :
                                            marker.type == "ponds" ? <SvgXml xml={pondXml}/> :
                                                marker.type == "beach" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlBeach}/> :
                                                    marker.type == "architecture" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlArchitecture}/> :
                                                        marker.type == "forest" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlForest}/> :
                                                            marker.type == "abandoned" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlAbandoned}/> :
                                                                marker.type == "caves" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlCave}/> :
                                                                    marker.type == "careers" ? <SvgXml xml={xmlCareers}/> :
                                                                        marker.type == "waterfall" ?
                                                                            <SvgXml xml={xmlWaterfall}/> :
                                                                            marker.type == "capes" ?
                                                                                <SvgXml xml={xmlCapes}/> :
                                                                                marker.type == "fields" ?
                                                                                    <SvgXml xml={xmlFields}/> :
                                                                                    marker.type == "canyons" ?
                                                                                        <SvgXml xml={xmlCanyons}/> :
                                                                                        <View><Text> LOL </Text></View>
                                    }
                                </Marker>
                            )
                        })}
                    </MapView>
                    <Searchbar
                        iconColor='white'
                        style={{
                            position: 'absolute',
                            top: hp('7.5%'),
                            maxWidth: wp('97%'),
                            alignSelf: "center",
                            borderRadius: '10%',
                            opacity: '0.8'
                        }} placeholder="Поиск" onChangeText={() => {
                    }} value=""/>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} style={{
                        left: wp('2%'),
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: hp('7%'),
                        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
                        width: wp('12%'),
                        height: hp('5%'),
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        marginTop: wp('2%'),
                        borderRadius: hp('1%'),
                    }}>
                        <Ionicons
                            style={{alignSelf: "center"}} color={'#000000'} size={hp('4%')}
                            name={"menu"}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => setSatellite((prev) => !prev)} style={{
                        right: wp('2%'),
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: hp('7%'),
                        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                        width: wp('12%'),
                        height: hp('5%'),
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        marginTop: wp('2%'),
                        borderRadius: hp('1%'),
                    }}>
                        <Ionicons
                        style={{alignSelf: "center"}} color={'#000000'} size={hp('4%')}
                        name={"layers-outline"}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.5} onPress={() => navigateToUserPosition()} style={{
                        right: wp('2%'),
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: hp('85%'),
                        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                        width: wp('12%'),
                        height: hp('5%'),
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        marginTop: wp('2%'),
                        backgroundColor: "#DBD7D2",
                        borderRadius: hp('1%'),
                    }}>
                        <Ionicons
                            style={{alignSelf: "center"}} color={'#000000'} size={hp('4%')}
                            name={"navigate-circle-outline"}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            );
    } else {
    return (
        <LinearGradient colors={['#051345', '#fa3c01']} style={{flex: 1}}>
            <StatusBar style="light"/>
            <LottieView
                style={{}}
                autoPlay={true} source={require('./../../../assets/lottie/mapAnimation.json')}
            />
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: hp('2%'), alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', top: hp('90%')}}>
                Загружаем красивые места...
            </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
    )
}
};
export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `KeyboardAvoidingView` and remove `flex: 1` of yours first `View`:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="position" enabled>
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
  <View>
   ...
  </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: When I add `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` my map disappears, and my keyboard doesn't dismiss even for the first time I open Map screen.

Answer (score 0):

Found simple and useful solution. In case you are using input in your map component you can also use it:

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
<MapView
  onPress = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss()}}
  onRegionChange = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss()}}
>
</MapView>
```

OnPress will close the keyboard when you press the map.
OnRegionChange will close the keyboard when you move the map.